# golang time.Sleep bug?

Tags: time, go

I make test code below(gotest.go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "sync"
)        

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go testa()    

    wg.Wait()
}

func testa() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("test goroutine")
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

console

```
go run gotest.go
```

and, change my computer's date 
(ex : 2015-07-30 -> 2015-07-29)

and then, 
println not printed!!

is it bug??

(It is working to set next day)

I use MacOs latest ver.
Thank you.

Comment: I have no such behaviour on windows machine. Maybe it's a bug on unix machines, cause for example using of time comparsion in time.Sleep function

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Internally sleep is done with absolute time: if you call `Sleep(n)` at time `T` the program is scheduled not to wake up **after** `n` time, but **at** time `T + n`.

This is generally preferable because:

- time usually does not flow backwards
- due to OS scheduling delays a program which repeatedly sleeps may lag behind schedule indefinitely; using absolute time make it compensate for delays by sleeping for shorter intervals.

In your case, you just have to wait for a day for the program to start printing again. :D

Or set a time just a little in the past (say 15 sec), and see the program resuming after 15+2 sec.

PS. To clarify what happens with an example:

At 2016-08-25 16:27:12 the program calls `time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)`
The Go runtime schedules the goroutine to be woken up on 2016-08-25 at 16:27:14 and puts the goroutine to sleep

meanwhile ...

the user sets the system time to 2016-08-**24** 16:27:13

now the timeout is scheduled to expire one day and one second later.

This should not happen on systems, on which Go uses POSIX CLOCK_MONOTONIC or equivalent thereof.

Comment: But this isn't true, or do I miss something? Here are docs for `time.Sleep`: ( https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep ) _Sleep pauses the current goroutine for at least the duration d. A negative or zero duration causes Sleep to return immediately_

Comment: I verified and `time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)` indeed puts my goroutine to sleep for 1 second.

Comment: This the `time.Sleep` interface; I said **internally** the interface is implemented with absolute timeout, see https://golang.org/src/runtime/time.go#L54

Answer (score 3):

time.Sleep(20_000_000_000) n is nanoseconds

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29853198)